# Upload large file to aws S3 server in .Net (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, aws-sdk

I need to upload multiple large files (Several GB) to AWS S3 server. I wrote basic code but it is giving error -

```
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

May be due to timeout.
So, is there any perfect way to upload large files to s3.
I am using below code-

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(this._s3Client);
TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
      {
         BucketName = s3BucketName,
         FilePath = filePath,
         PartSize = 6291456,
         Key = key,
         CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
       };
fileTransferUtilityRequest.UploadProgressEvent += FileTransferUtilityRequest_UploadProgressEvent;
fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
```

Comment: did you check the command line logs or the aspnet logs in IIS to confirm that this is a timeout issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the `Timeout` parameter as part of the `TransferUtilityUploadRequest`?

If so you could use a reasonable large number, or if you are desperate you could use `-1` for infinite. This is obviously not recommended.

**Associated Documentation:** 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityUploadRequest.htm

Comment: But TimeOut property is not available in TransferUtilityUploadRequest.

Comment: @AshishKumar are you sure? Their docs list it:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityUploadRequest.htm